# How to disable the keyboard shortcut to switch between workspaces?

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspace-switcher, ubuntu-mate

There are a ton of questions and guides about how to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> work to switch between workspaces -- I'm having the opposite problem.

**"Switch between workspaces" works just fine -- but I want to disable it** because it overrides the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Down</kbd> of an app I need to use (plus, I usually switch between workspaces differently, by using the mouse scroll wheel on the pager in the system panel).

**I'm using Ubuntu Mate 15.10** and the guides that talk about using `gconf-editor` seem to not apply -- it doesn't look anything like the (plain Ubuntu) screen shots in the guides.

Comment: Hi KlaymenDK, got it, although not in gsettings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### How to disable or change the keyboard shortcut to switch workspaces

---

### 1. On Ubuntu Mate

Although I am pretty sure the keyboard *custom keybindings* must be in a `gsettings` key somewhere in Mate as well, a quick search gave no result(s). That is a pity, since an elegant (automatic) solution would be preferable.

*However*

To change or disable the workspace-switch keybindings manually, choose:

***System > Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard Shortcuts > Window Management*** *(section)*

Then simply click on the shortcut key (on the right) and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to disable the shortcut.

[image]

You could of course set another one alternatively.

> ## If the Workspace Actions are Missing
>
> For the workspace actions to show up in the Keyboard Shortcuts list, you may need to have at least two workspaces configured. On my machine, I had already disabled all the workspace functionality, but the keyboard shortcut was still being intercepted by Gnome. Reenabling workspaces and setting it so there were two available caused the actions to reappear in Keyboard Shortcuts so that I could remove those shortcuts.

#### Note

The weird thing is that *after disabling* the shortcut via GUI, the shortcut could be controlled, similarly to the way it is done in Gnome/Unity. Not sure what to do with it, but wanted to mention...

### 2. On Unity / Gnome

***Using gsettings commands***

The keybindings to switch to another workspace are set in:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

- To *disable* the keybindings to move up/down/left/right, run the commands:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up []
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down []
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left []
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right []
  ```
- To *reset*:

  ```
  gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up
  ```

  (`down/left/right`)

This applies to both 14.04 and 15.04+

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't make any noticeable difference. I even rebooted my workstation.

Comment: I can use the commands (also "get" and "reset") so they do seem to work -- they're just not the ones in control of these shortcuts.

Comment: @KlaymenDK That surprises me, tested on Unity and Gnome, will install Mate on VM to take a look.

Comment: @KlaymenDK While waiting for it to install... what is the application? there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: You really make an effort, don't you? Wow. The application is Eclipse, where it duplicates lines.

Comment: That is weird, I don't see the options you do. I'll post a screen shot: https://imgur.com/aMlEYDc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36796/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-klaymendk).

Comment: This key combination is also used to copy lines in very popular editor Visual Studio Code. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/509

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS no longer has this option.